# $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ are i.i.d RVs uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$.

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ be independent identically distributed random variables uniform on $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$, and let: $Y_n:=\text{the number of different elements in } \{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$.

Let $T:=\inf\{n:Y_n=N\}$.

What is $E\left[T\right]$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\inf\{n:Y_n=N\}$?

Comment: The question is asking for the expected value of the random minimum sample size $T$ needed to be observed from a discrete uniform variable on $[1, N]$ such that every value in the support is observed.  Clearly, ${\rm E}[T] \ge N$.

Comment: @enthdegree the smallest n s.t. Yn=N.i.e. the first time we have N different elements in {x1,x2,...,xn}.

Comment: Get it now, thanks!

Comment: @heropup  You are right!Thank you for the explanation

Comment: @enthdegree It is my fault.I guess there should be some trick to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is commonly known as the **coupon collector's problem.**  See here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: It is a good answer!